# How Can Define Dict For Multiple Uses?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a 'general' function for multiple uses with different amounts of keys and cds, what is a way to do it? How can I state how many keys(and, therefore, cds) I am going to need in the function? Thank you!

```
def get_keyboard(key1, cd1, key2, cd2,key3, cd3):
  cb_data1 = menu_cb.new(subsection=cd1)
  cb_data2 = menu_cb.new(subsection=cd2)
  cb_data3 = menu_cb.new(subsection=cd3)
  inline_button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(key1,callback_data=cb_dat1)
  inline_button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(key2,callback_data=cb_dat2)
  inline_button3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(key3,callback_data=cb_dat3)
  return types.
    InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3).
    row(inline_button1,inline_button2, inline_button3)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your use case here? How will you be using this data?

Comment: I want the function to know how many key-cd pairs are needed, and from there, the function should be able to create the types.InlineKeyboardButton() lines for each key-cd pair stated.

Comment: Just pick a good data structure involving a list.

Answer (score 0):

This does what was asked for:

```
def get_keyboard(*args):
    inline_buttons = []

    for key, cd in zip(args[::2], args[1::2]):
        cb_data = menu_cb.new(subsection=cd)
        inline_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(key, callback_data=cb_data)
        inline_buttons.append(inline_button)

    return (
        types
        .InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=len(inline_buttons))
        .row(*inline_buttons)
    )
```

But this might be a better function signature:

```
def get_keyboard(key_cd_pairs):
    for key, cd in key_cd_pairs:
        ...
```

Or even the simple:

```
def get_keyboard(keys, cds):
    for key, cd in zip(keys, cds):
        ...
```